# How to serve a WASM file

Tags: go

I have a small WASM program that I would like to test on my private LAN (mostly mobile devices). I am able to serve it on local loopback. I was hoping to create a simple page route in go that would handle the WASM and serve it to devices on my network. Unfortunately the application/wasm content type isn't recognized (I think).

Is there an easy way to serve the index.html that has embedded WASM?

I am not sure how to modify this to allow for the Content-Type:

```
package main

import (
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    port := os.Getenv("PORT")
    if port == "" {
    port = "5000"
    }

    f, _ := os.Create("/var/log/golang/golang-server.log")
    defer f.Close()
    log.SetOutput(f)

    const indexPage = "public/index.html"
    http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        log.Printf("Serving %s to %s...\n", indexPage, r.RemoteAddr)
        http.ServeFile(w, r, indexPage)
    })

    log.Printf("Listening on port %s\n\n", port)
    http.ListenAndServe(":"+port, nil)
}
```

Comment: maybe you should also post to "webassembly" tag

Comment: @AJR no, it's not "webassembly" issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What does it mean "index.html that has embedded WASM"?

I suppose you have separate WASM file, located somewhere in your filesystem.
In go documentation it is recommended to use WASM files like this:

```
WebAssembly.instantiateStreaming(fetch("main.wasm"), go.importObject).
    then((result) => {
            go.run(result.instance);
    });
```

so browser when loads index.html also asks your webserver for `main.wasm` file. You have to handle it explicitly (add this call after your previous call to http.HandleFunc):

```
http.HandleFunc("/main.wasm", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    log.Printf("Serving WASM to %s...\n", r.RemoteAddr)
    http.ServeFile(w, r, "path/to/wasm/file")
})
```

But much more simple way of serving static content (including `.wasm` files) is serving hole directory with assets (usually I place all required resources into this folder - js, css, images, etc):

```
http.Handle(
    "/assets/", 
    http.StripPrefix("/assets/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("path/to/assets/folder")))
)
```

In this case replace JavaScript code `instantiateStreaming(fetch("main.wasm"), go.importObject)` with `instantiateStreaming(fetch("/assets/main.wasm"), go.importObject)` and place your wasm file into assets folder.

Comment: @jeffspicoli very strange - I did the same thing week ago and my mobile phone gets wasm well. Maybe browser on your phone doesn't support wasm? Anyway - i agree that this technology is not perfect now and I don't recommend to use it in production. For example wasm files are too heavy (unless you are compiling with tinygo).